# How to work with classes that change in styled-components

Tags: javascript, styled-components

This question may have been asked, but I'm having trouble finding the answer.  I'm new to styled-components, but slowly starting to appreciate them.  I'm trying to understand how to grab the class name considering they change dynamically.  The code I'm doing is:

**styled-component**

```
export const NavOpen = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 30px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
`;
```

**javascript**

```
const slideInWindow = display => {
  if (display) {
    const navWindow = document.querySelector(".sc-ifAKCX");
    navWindow.classList.add("slidein");
  }
};
```

**JSX**

```
<NavOpen onClick={() => slideInWindow(true)}>
  <Bar1 />
  <Bar2 />
  <Bar3 />
  {display && <X onClick={() => closeWindow(false)} />}
</NavOpen>
```

The class .sc-ifAKCX was something different before.  I'm sure I'm going at this wrong, but trying to understand how I should query the class if it's going to change on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give each styled component a class name of your choosing:

```
export const NavOpen = styled.div.attrs({
  className: 'slidein-target'
})`
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 30px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
`;
```

Now every `NavOpen` instance will have the class `slidein-target` in it's classlist, which you can use as your query selector.

Note that `slidein-target` will not replace the generated class name `sc-XXXXXX` but will appear alongside it.

Comment: Is this good practice?  Is this the intended result or just a work around?

Comment: If you could mark this as correct I would appreciate it. Direct dom manipulation is considered dangerous in React, but it's not terrible as long as you're aware of the potential issues. [This is an official reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-dom-manipulation-plugins), I suggest reading it. Basically they suggest isolating that component from the rest of your markup and tying it's manipulation to lifecycle methods. There is probably a more "Reacty" way you could do what you're trying to do, but this isn't an inherently bad solution